# Magento 1.9 Error log shows undefined variable: id

Tags: magento-1.9, error-log

I have this error appers all the time in the system.log file. How to fix it?

```
ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: id  in /ext/vhosts/mysite.com/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 224
ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: id  in /ext/vhosts/mysite.com/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 225
```

I'm using Magento 1.9.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice errors aren't critical, but it's better fixing them. However, Magento shouldn't display throw notice errors, so I suspect it could be coming from a custom module/theme.

To debug this (in a **dev environment only**): open up 
`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php` and add:

```
public function load($id, $field=null)
{
    if (!isset($id)) {
        echo Varien_Debug::backtrace(true, true);
        exit;
    }
    $this->_beforeLoad($id, $field);
    ...
```

Then refresh the page, and you should see a backtrace of the error, and by going up the backtrace, you can see what module/theme tries to load an object with an `NULL` id.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'backtrace of the error'?

Comment: A backtrace is like a detailed path of a PHP process. So you can see exactly what executed what, where from and in what order

Comment: Where can that information be found? Exception.log?

Comment: No, if you make the edit I have added above, it will be printed on the screen when you refresh